# Delete end part of a filename

Tags: windows-7

How can I rename a list of files using powershell when the filename format is the following?

CCP-01333.3.03 301DA839E9F736B1042568140001C7C6.htm

I just want to delete everything after the space (301DA839E9F736B1042568140001C7C6) but still keeping the ".htm" extension.

it would be then  -->  CCP-01333.3.03.htm

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all files in the directory are candidates:

```
Dir | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “ *“,”” }
```

If you have a mixed set of files:

```
Dir CCP*.htm | Rename-Item –NewName { $_.name –replace “ *“,”” }
```